# Dependency Injection to few arguments

Tags: php

i dont really understand why i get this Error Message and i hope you guys can help:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Controller\Home::__construct(), 0 passed in /mnt/c/mvc/index.php on line 25 and exactly 1 expected in /mnt/c/mvc/src/Controller/Home.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/c/mvc/index.php(25): App\Controlyler\Home->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /mnt/c/mvc/src/Controller/Home.php on line 12

index.php

```
declare(strict_types=1);


ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use App\Core\{Router, Request};
use App\Service\View;


require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Core/Bootstrap.php';


$routerLoad = Router::load('src/core/Routes.php')
    ->direct(Request::uri());

$routerAction = new $routerLoad;

$routerAction->action();

$view = new View();
$view->display();
```

Home.php

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\ViewInterface;
use App\Service\View;

class Home implements Controller
{
    private ViewInterface $view;

    public function __construct(View $view)
    {
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function action(): void
    {
        $this->view->addTemplate('layout.tpl');
        $this->view->addTlpParam('headline', 'Home');
        $this->view->addTlpParam('info', 'Welcome');
        $this->view->addTlpParam('name', 'User');
        $this->view->display();
    }
}
```

View.php

```
namespace App\Service;

class View implements ViewInterface
{
    private \Smarty  $smarty;
    private string $template;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->smarty = new \Smarty();
        $this->smarty->setTemplateDir('/mnt/c/mvc/src/View/templates');
        $this->smarty->setCompileDir('/mnt/c/mvc/src/smarty/templates_c');
        $this->smarty->setCacheDir('/mnt/c/mvc/src/smarty/cache');
        $this->smarty->setConfigDir('/mnt/c/mvc/src/smarty/configs');
    }

    public function addTemplate(string $template):void
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function addTlpParam(string $name, $value): void
    {
        $this->smarty->assign($name, $value);
    }

    public function display(): void
    {
        try {
            $this->smarty->display($this->template);
        } catch (\SmartyException $e) {
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your other scripts something is trying to instantiate the `Home` controller and it's not passing the view into the constructor.

Comment: *"Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Controller\Home::__construct(), 0 passed in /mnt/c/mvc/index.php on line 25 ..."* You are not passing all arguments as the message suggests. **Where exactly is line 25 in index.php?**